# Two forms one view: model variable loses value

Tags: python, django

Here's my code

```
@login_required
def upload(request):
    form_type = ''
    transcript = Transcript()
    transcript.file_path = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file_form' in request.POST:
            file_form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if file_form.is_valid():
                path = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], request.user)
                transcript.file_path = path
                transcript.user = request.user
                export_form = InfoForm()
                form_type = 'info_form'
        elif 'info_form' in request.POST:
            if transcript.file_path:
                info_form = InfoForm(request.POST)
                if info_form.is_valid():
                    transcript.user = request.user
                    transcript.title = info_form.cleaned_data.get('title')
                    transcript.instructions = info_form.cleaned_data.get('instructions')
                    transcript.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks')
            else:
                raise ValueError('Transcript object has no file path attribute')
    else:
        export_form = FileForm()
        form_type = 'file_form'

    return render(request, 'transcription/upload.html', {'form': export_form, 'form_type': form_type})
```

always, the file-form is called before the info-form, so the code in the if statement

```
 if transcript.file_path:
    #...
```

should always execute. But the ValueError always gets raised, meaning `transcript.file_path` is reset. How does this happen, and how can it be fixed?

file_form and info_form in POST are names of the different submit buttons, so I know which form I am dealing with.

```
def handle_uploaded_file(file, user):
    id = randint(0, 10000)
    user_dir = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + str(user.id).replace(".", "") + '/'
    path = user_dir + file.name.replace(".mp3", str(id) + ".mp3")
    if not os.path.exists(user_dir):
        os.makedirs(user_dir)
    with open(path, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
        file = File(destination)
        info = {'path': path, 'file': file}
    return path
```

Comment: In the third line of your method you are doing `transcript.file_path = ''`...  so that if block will never execute.

Comment: It does execute because the if statement doesn't test for file_path. The problem is in the second if block. It executes but raises that Value Error @solarissmoke

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Your if statement **does** test for `file_path`. What is happening is simple. In line three you set `transcript.file_path = ''`. In line 14 is you check `if transcript.file_path` which will always be false because you just set it to `''`. Hence the `else` block executes and you get the `ValueError`.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the first block `if 'file_form' in request.POST:` always executes before the block `elif 'info_form' in request.POST:`. In fact, there's no way to get to the second block without going through the first because the second form is put on the page by `export_form = InfoForm()
                form_type = 'info_form'`. So the value of `transcript.file_path` should be changed in the first if block, and, consequently, the ValueError should never be raised.

Comment: It is not possible for both those blocks to be executed in succession... that is the definition of `elif`! The `elif` portion can only ever execute if the `if` portion did not!

Comment: I call the function twice. The first time the `if` executes, and starts creating the object. The second time the `elif` executes, completing the object. @solarissmoke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a rookie mistake. 
I didn't know that during each post request the whole view gets called again.
So I just initialized my variables

```
form_type = ''
transcript = Transcript()
transcript.file_path = ''
```

outside the view and voila!

Comment: For what it's worth, this is not a good idea, and will cause you all sorts of problems going forward, especially if you use a multi-threaded environment in production. you have no thread safety here and will get unexpected and very confusing behaviour. If you need to persist variables then pass them as arguments to your function.